# Running cluster and outlier analysis gives ERROR 999998?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, clustering, outlier, error-999998

I am attempting to run Cluster and Outlier Analysis on a Shapefile Feature Class. The geometry type is a line feature class. I am receiving the following error when attempting to use this tool:

> error 999998: unexpected error

I am really not sure where to start on resolving this problem.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense to run this type of statistic on a line feature class. There is no way to construct a spatial weights matrix. These tools are intended for points and polygons.